# has_many :through mixed with belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm having trouble with the following scenario: a *user* can work at one or more *companies* and a *company* can have zero or more *users* working there.  The "catch" for me is that I need to track what *user* was responsible for *create* the company record.

**Tables**

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateCompanies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :companies do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateWorks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :works do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :company_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**Models**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :companies

  has_many :works
  has_many :companies, :through => :works

end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :user_id

  belongs_to :user

  has_many :works
  has_many :users, :through => :works

end

class Work < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :company_id, :user_id

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :company



end
```

How must I procced in order to create the company record (if it doesn't exist), register the *user_id* of the creator in **company** table and also create the association in **works** table?

The idea is later create a form where the current user can choose where he/she works (if the company already exists) or create the company record and register the association.